# How to find the frequency of a word in a line, in a text file - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, word-count

I have managed to make an RDD (in Pyspark) that looks like this:

```
[('This', (0, 1)), ('is', (0, 1)), ('the', (0, 1)), ('100th', (0, 1))...]
```

I used the following code:
`RDD=sc.textFile(_filepath_)`

`test1 = RDD.zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda x: ((i,(x[1],1)) for i in x[0].split(" ")))`

Practically, `[(word, (line, freq)]`  so the above words are from the 1st line in the file (hence the 0) and `freq` is 1 for all words in the text, and I want it to count the times this word appears on this specific line, for the entire RDD.
I thought of  `.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)` but when I execute an action like `.take(5)` after that, it freezes (Ubuntu terminal - Oracle VirtualBox with plenty of RAM/disk space, if it helps).

What I need is basically, if the word 'This' is in first line and it's there 7 times, then the result will be `[('This', (0, 7)), ...]`

Comment: Do not post images or links to code, in questions.  Please edit your question to include the image text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, but the answer may not be optimal.

```
RDD = sc.textFile(_filepath_) 
test1 = RDD.zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda x: ((i,(x[1],1)) for i in x[0].split(" "))) 
test2 = test1.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1][0]), x[1][1])).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) 
Result_RDD = test2.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1])))
```